# Display the list of literature in the table of contents

Tags: tables

[image]

**What do I need to change that my literature list is gonna be shown in the table of contents?

Thanks for your help!!!

Best regards, Amir**

Comment: Most likely you need to switch `\bibliography` and `\addcontentsline`. Regardless, this should work to place *something* in the ToC (you have to compile at least twice on the first go). Can you provide a screen shot of the ToC?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The thing is when I just type the coded \bibliography{  } without any argument, like mentioned here the literaure list is shown in the content but then the literature list is empty without any entries....

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`?

Comment: Do you have some example photo of  the result you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tocbibind` package which lets you control some of the ToC entries. By default the Bibliography, Index, ToC, LoT, LoF titles will be put into the ToC. You can prevent any of these from appearing.

As you didn't provide an MWE for us to try, I'm not providing one for you to try. --- GOM